# React Native Expo Router Tabs: How to set Tab Name and Icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using `expo-router` in my React Native expo app, and my files are

```
├── app
│   ├── (main)
│   └── _layout.js
│   └── _foo.js
│   └── _bar.js
```

**`layout.js`**

```js
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function Layout() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Tabs>
          <Tabs.Screen name="foo" screenOptions={{ title: "Foo" }} />
          <Tabs.Screen name="bar" screenOptions={{ title: "Bar" }} />
        </Tabs>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
```

However, the 2 tab buttons showing on my iOS device have titles `foo` and `bar` instead of `Foo` and `Bar`.

What is the correct way to set the names for the tab buttons?

Also, is there a way to rearrange the order of the tab buttons? Such as showing `[ Foo | Bar ]` instead of `[ Bar | Foo ]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just change screenOptions to options instead. And title to tabBarLabel

```
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function Layout() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Tabs>
          <Tabs.Screen name="foo" options={{ tabBarLabel: "Foo" }} />
          <Tabs.Screen name="bar" options={{ tabBarLabel: "Bar" }} />
        </Tabs>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For icons, you can use the `react-native-vector-icons` library ([Link for the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)). Or you can follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkjYTapyEO8&ab_channel=Arslan).

For Title: Whatever name you will give in name prop of component will be displayed in tab bar.
I have used [these docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation) for the tab navigation.

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default function Layout() {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, size}) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'Foo') {
            iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Bar') {
            iconName = focused ? 'basketball' : 'basketball-outline';
          }
          return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={'pink'} />;
        },
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          color: 'pink',
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        },
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Foo" component={'You Component Name'} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Bar" component={'You Component Name'} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the names-> use the options prop

```
<Tabs.Screen
  name="foo"
  options={{
    title: 'Foo'
  }}
/>
```

Rearrange your tabs -> simple define your tabs in the order you want them to appear

```
<Tabs>
  <Tabs.Screen name="foo" options={{ title: "Foo" }} />
  <Tabs.Screen name="bar" options={{ title: "Bar" }} />
</Tabs>
```

NB name refers to the name of your file so the file should be called foo.js

SafeAreaProvider is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Tabs.Screen` options `tabBarLabel` and `tabBarIcon`. `tabBarIcon` has the following definition:

```
tabBarIcon?: ({
  focused: boolean;
  color: string;
  size: number;
}) => React.ReactNode) | undefined
```

Using FontAwesome as an example here, but other icon options will work here as well.

```
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Tabs>
        <Tabs.Screen name="foo" options={{ tabBarLabel: "Foo", tabBarIcon: () => <FontAwesome name="home" /> }} />
        <Tabs.Screen name="bar" options={{ tabBarLabel: "Bar", tabBarIcon: () => <FontAwesome name="gear" /> }} />
      </Tabs>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```